# Using Drop Down Box with multiple selection item using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using a drop down with checkbox where i can select more that one item and i am using it to insert the data into  my detailview.  My issue is that if i select more than one item from the drop down, it only inserts the first item that is selected even though i selected more than one item from the drop down box.  What am i doing wrong here?  Pls. help

```
 protected void DetailsView1_ItemInserting(object sender, DetailsViewInsertEventArgs e)
    {

        foreach (ListItem listItem in cblCustomerList.Items)
        {
            if (listItem.Selected)
            {

                string GroupName = cblCustomerList.SelectedValue;


            sqlcon.Open();
            string eno = ((TextBox)DetailsView1.FindControl("txteno")).Text.ToString();
            string empname = ((TextBox)DetailsView1.FindControl("txtempname")).Text.ToString();
            string sal = ((TextBox)DetailsView1.FindControl("txtsal")).Text.ToString();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select eno from emp where eno = '" + eno + "'", sqlcon);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.Read())
            {
                lblmsg.Text = "Employee No already exists";
            }
            else
            {
                dr.Close();
                sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("insert into emp values('" + eno + "', '" + empname + "','" + sal + "' , '" + GroupName + "')", sqlcon);
                sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
              //  DetailsView1.ChangeMode(DetailsViewMode.Insert);
            }
            sqlcon.Close();
           // LoadDet();
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should use the [SelectedItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selecteditems.aspx) property of the ListBox, which  gives you a collection of all selected items (you can then get their values). It's easier than manually going through all the items.

The issue in your code is that you use the `SelectedValue` property of `cblCustomerList`, while you should use the `Value` property of `listItem`.

Try this:

```
protected void DetailsView1_ItemInserting(object sender, DetailsViewInsertEventArgs e)
{

    foreach (ListItem listItem in cblCustomerList.Items)
    {
        if (listItem.Selected)
        {

            string GroupName = listItem.Value; // fix is here


        sqlcon.Open();
        string eno = ((TextBox)DetailsView1.FindControl("txteno")).Text.ToString();
        string empname = ((TextBox)DetailsView1.FindControl("txtempname")).Text.ToString();
        string sal = ((TextBox)DetailsView1.FindControl("txtsal")).Text.ToString();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select eno from emp where eno = '" + eno + "'", sqlcon);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.Read())
        {
            lblmsg.Text = "Employee No already exists";
        }
        else
        {
            dr.Close();
            sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("insert into emp values('" + eno + "', '" + empname + "','" + sal + "' , '" + GroupName + "')", sqlcon);
            sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
          //  DetailsView1.ChangeMode(DetailsViewMode.Insert);
        }
        sqlcon.Close();
       // LoadDet();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, i have done what you suggested but still it is inserting the first selected item only.  I believe the problem is here: if (dr.Read()) and i could be wrong but please help if u can... thanks

Comment: i fixed that was the issue i mentioned.  thanks for your help.